# Help Patching a driver

Tags: raspbian, kernel, driver, pi-4

I've been tasked with updating a driver on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian. I'm told I need to apply this patch https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/4/1/1050 in order to get my USB modem to work.

When I run uname -r
I'm told I'm on kernel version 4.19.75-v7l+

I created the option.c file in the directory /lib/modules/4.19.75-v7l+/kernel/drivers/usb/serial but I can't figure out how to 'apply?/patch?/compile?/update?' these changes to the option.ko file in the directory?

Thank you for any help

Comment: You cannot patch a compiled binary object such as a `.ko` file with source code.  The file (`option.c`) is referenced directly in the patch (for use with the `patch` tool).  *You then have to compile that to create a new `.ko` file and replace it in `/lib/modules`.*  I'll warn you your chance of failure here is pretty high.

Comment: That fix is already in the Raspberry Pi kernel source at https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/e2d2941326922b63d722ebc46520c3a2287b675f/drivers/usb/serial/option.c. Try running `sudo rpi-update && sudo reboot` to get the very latest kernel.

Answer (score 3):

For such a small patch I wouldn't bother using a tool to apply it. Just add the lines starting with the `+` sign to [`option.c`](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/drivers/usb/serial/option.c), not including the `+` sign itself. The first insertion will be at line 249, and another three lines should be inserted at line 1091 (or 1092 after you insert the first one).

Bigger patches must be saved into a file and applied using a compatible tool, usually `patch` or `git apply`.

Comment: I believe the file I need to patch is "option.ko" which I can't open with any text editor.

Comment: @fullyjosh No, `.ko` files are compilation outputs. Patches are applied to source code. This patch mention its target: `drivers/usb/serial/option.c`

Comment: So after I create the option.c file (there was no existing file previously) there's nothing more I need to do?

Comment: You need to get the kernel source code (which will create `option.c`), modify that file and then rebuild the kernel module (`usbserial.ko`?) or maybe build it into a custom kernel.

Comment: Don't bother.  That patch is already in the kernel source: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.19.y/drivers/usb/serial/option.c

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question but how do I get to the kernel source code? I have a few other patches I need to apply in addition to this one. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @fullyjosh I suppose you should start with `git clone https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux`, and browse though [examples](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki/Examples-on-how-to-build-various-modules) of how one builds a kernel module while you're getting the sources.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been tasked with updating a driver on a Raspberry Pi 4 running Raspbian. I'm told I need to apply this patch https://lkml.org/lkml/2019/4/1/1050 in order to get my USB modem to work.

You are in luck in the sense that that patch has already been applied.  Here is the relevant source file in what is approximately the current Pi kernel source:

https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/blob/rpi-4.14.y/drivers/usb/serial/option.c

I also checked 4.14, since that LKML post appears to be dated 2019 and refers to 4.14.  You can check your current kernel version with `uname -r`.  If it is less than 4.14 you should upgrade.

If you already have a current kernel but the modem still does not work, this is probably not such great news (perhaps consider an [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/66378/212479) here).  To dispell any doubts, you can read up [on how the `patch` utility works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_(Unix)) (see also `man patch`); in short the lines marked on the left with `+` in that patch file are to be added to the target.  The rest is there for context.

What that amounts to is simply adding the USB ID for a particular make and model of device; there's no real functional code there.  These are used by the kernel to associate USB devices (which provide an ID) with drivers.  You can see these with `lsusb` (you may need to `apt install usbutils`).  That modem will appear as
`2c7c:0512`.  The first number is the `QUECTEL_VENDOR_ID`, the second the `QUECTEL_PRODUCT_EM12` ID.  Note `lsusb` will show it regardless of whether an appropriate driver is loaded or available (ie., this does not indicate it works).

I don't think these are strictly necessary in order to use the driver; you can manually load it (`sudo modprobe option`; you can see if it is loaded with `lsmod | grep option`).  The ID, again, is so it can be automatically loaded when the device is plugged in.